# How to change key signature on Google account manager 5.1 apk to match Google account manager 7.1 using lucky patcher

Tags: google

Can't install old version of apk Google account manager 5.1 cause it says file is corrupt or file exists under same name...solution lies in giving the old version of Google account manager 5.1 the same key signature as the already been Google account manager 7.1....how do I change the signature using lucky patcher?

Comment: "Google account manager" is not a regular app. Hence it seems you are talking about custom ROM right? And you are trying to update one app of the GApps package?

Comment: My phone has no Google account at all...it won't let me add an account...the only way I can add one is to install the old version of Google account manager 5.1...but I can't uninstall Google account manager 7.1.... Everytime I turn the phone off I have to do the frp bypass again...nobody knows the email or password to the original email...

Comment: I either need to change the key signature of the Google account manager 5.1 to mimic the 7.1 or root the phone...don't have a computer and don't have a otg cable....device is a ZTE blade and it is running Android nougat 7.1.1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959890/android-app-not-install-an-existing-package-by-the-same-name-with-a-conflicting that is the link with the solution

Answer (score 0):

> how do I change the signature using lucky patcher?

You can't. Apps on Android are signed using a private key. The signature is computed from the private key and the contents of the APK file. You can't copy a signature from one app to another: if you could, there would be no point having a signature.

To make the signatures match, the same person who built the APK file you already have installed must build the new APK file, and sign it using the same private key. In your case, that's probably the author of the custom ROM. That's the process the SO question you linked is talking about.